# Console App / Task Scheduler

Tags: vb.net, scheduled-tasks, console-application

I have a console app written in VB Net that works perfectly.  Now I want to run it using task scheduler.  The problem is that the app has a console.readline command at the very end that keeps the console window open until the user hits enter.  Is there a way to test whether the app is running in a session or not?

If I knew that the app was not tied to a desktop console, I would not write the comments to the console and I'd bypass the final console.readline command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add an argument to your task to indicate it is unattended. For example, pass `/u` in your scheduled task. Check for `/u` in your program to determine if it should skip the `console.readline`.

[image]

excerpt from [msdn forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/51379b07-7fd3-495a-b2bc-830462fe0fa1/visual-basic-console-application-with-arguments)

```
Dim args() As String = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()

' args(0) = Full path of executing program with program name
' args(1) = First switch in command - /u
if args(1) = "/u" then ....
```

Or you can change the signature of your `Main()` to `Public Sub Main(ByVal args() As String)` and you won't need to use `Dim args() As String = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`

Comment: I was hoping there was a relatively easy way to identify that the app was running under the Task Scheduler or the window handle was zero or something.  That would be a whole lot more fun!!!